# Inserting map/scene from react-arcgis with legend inside

Tags: reactjs, arcgis

I am inserting maps in react app.
I am following examples from package "react-arcgis".

Like:
(Map component - name Mapw.js)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Map } from 'react-arcgis';

export default (props) => (
<Map
    style={{ width: '100vw', height: '100vh' }}
    mapProperties={{ basemap: 'satellite' }}
/>
)
```

And using like:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Mapw from './Mapw'

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
  <Mapw />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

It is working but it has the undesired effect like image below:

[Map showing with legends and controls outside map image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adPfK.png)

Could someone shed some light on how display a clean map that I could use like above or integrate in other component, like a popup, but with the texts and controls integrated (or at least not visible and taking space)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to load the appropriate CSS stylesheet for the ArcGIS JS API in your html. That should solve this problem.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.4/esri/css/main.css">
```

Comment: It fixed! Thank you